# MySQL sorting by 3 columns or UNION them

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem understandint `ORDER BY` in `MySQL`. I have to sort a table by 3 criteria

1 - first i want to sort by **TYPE_OF_WORK** so all data must be alphabetical, like

```
dech_rap_bus
dech_rap_bus
ger_dem_dech_bus
ger_dem_dech_bus
ger_dem_stp_pp
...
```

RESULT => http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b2a858/6

2 - second i want to sort by **PROJECT_VERSION** so all data must be alphabetical, but respecting the 1 criteria, like

```
dech_rap_bus            V123-V1234
dech_rap_bus            V300
ger_dem_dech_bus        V123-V1234  
ger_dem_dech_bus        V300
ger_dem_stp_pp          V123-V1234
```

RESULT => http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b2a858/7

So **1** and **2** are working perfectly.

3 - and after this i want to sort by the column **not_existing**

RESULT => http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b2a858/5

and i don't know what it really do, but i see no results ... i just want that the

dech_rap_bus    V300

where the **NOT_EXISTING** column is **1** to be at the end, and when are more of **NOT_EXISTING** = **1** to sort them all but at the end of the table.

I tought to myself that a UNION of 2 selects would help me

```
/* Selecting all data where  not_existing is not 1 or NULL ---> working good! */
(
    SELECT 
    * 
    FROM 
    atm_mti_view 
    WHERE 
    project_function='FRS01' AND 
    on_big_project_id = 12 AND
    (not_existing != 1 OR not_existing IS NULL)
    ORDER BY
    type_of_work ASC,
    project_version ASC
)

UNION

/* Selecting all data where  not_existing is 1 ---> working good! */
(
    SELECT 
    * 
    FROM 
    atm_mti_view 
    WHERE 
    project_function='FRS01' AND 
    on_big_project_id = 12 AND
    not_existing = 1
    ORDER BY
    type_of_work ASC,
    project_version ASC
)
```

but what this piece of code does, is putting the not existing dech_rap_bus at the end, good, but it messes up the version sorting, WHY???

SEE RESULT HERE => http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b2a858/8

Why is that? I just want to **MERGE** two select results, what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Why not just sort by NOT_EXISTING first? That will put them at the bottom - is that not what you want?

Comment: i tried that, didn't went well ..

Comment: Sorting by that will give you 'not existing' at the end and then the other two sorts in the order you want - what didn't go well?

Comment: believe me it dosen't do what i need, i can show you a screenshot of a bigger result

Comment: Can you explain the issue? Both the 'not_existing' = null and 'not_existing' = 1 are sorted in the same order but the nulls are first then the 1s are sorted

Comment: wait so i can upload a photo, because i cannot upload a bigger database on sqlfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do

```
order by 
 (case when not_existing is null then 0 else not_existing end) desc
,type_of_work ASC,
project_version ASC
```

It will come first.

your query is not ordering because you have different project value for dech_rap_bus

```
TYPE_OF_WORK    PROJECT_VERSION 
dech_rap_bus    V123-V1234  
dech_rap_bus    V300
```

Comment: I thought of adding the case but nulls come before 1 anyway so is there any definite need for it?

Comment: @Charleh: No , Its just to avoid nulls..  In some databases null might take differently

Comment: THIS IS WHAT MY CODE DOES -> here is the image http://www.imagetoo.com/images/firstimage.png --> as you can see, it stacks the V123-V1234, it's really weird, do you see? is this normal?

Comment: it is WORKING, OMG!! :)))) I've been working on this for the last 3 hours, and you answer it in 5 minutes, not bad ... thanks, but what is the logic ?!?

Comment: @Empeus: when you have multiple columns in the order by clause, it will take first column order the records, then take the second second column and order it and so on.. when it orders with second column it will order only within the group, not across the group

Comment: But the OP said they already ordered by not_existing first and it didn't work - I've tried sorting using a NULL and I get the same results with/without NULL - so what gives? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eb3cc/1 - does NULL actually affect the sort order vs 0?

Comment: what?? it is like re-ordering? i though that ORDER BY multiple columns, are done one by one respecting the highest rank 1 , 2 , 3 , right?

Comment: and about the NULL ... there not_existing can be NULL or 0 => show the record from top, 1 => show the record at the bottom

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't this give you what you want?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b2a858/26

Just sort by not_existing first?

What's the problem here? You have your sort but with not_existing records at the end - these are also sorted in the same way

Comment: wait so i can upload a photo, because i cannot upload a bigger database on sqlfiddle

Comment: here is the image http://www.imagetoo.com/images/firstimage.png --> as you can see, it stacks the V123-V1234, it's really weird, do you see?

Comment: Yes - are all those dech_rap_bus at the end all not_existing = 1? If so that is exactly what I'd expect - you are sorting by not_existing (to put them at the bottom) then sorting by type_of_work and then by version. What are you expecting it to do? Are you talking about the top? If so that is also correct - the versions are stacked because there are multiple type_of_works which are ordered first. If you want versions ordered first, change the sort to sort by version first - actually looking at the sort I see what you mean - probably because of the NULL

Comment: Try adding the case like Joe G Joseph suggested. It may be that it's treating the null as a separate group for each item

Comment: apparently i have 2 examples that are fully working, but i'm looking to solve it even this way, what i want is to have everything sorted by **type_of_work** and **project_version**, but that records that have **not_existing=1** to be at the bottom respecting the first 2 rules, got me?

Comment: thanks, i would give you an + but this things with databases, is still troubling me ...

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eb3cc/1 - I still don't see a difference with a normal sort when NULL is used though..! :P

Comment: i know, it is an enigma, my problem is solved, but take a look at this photo  imagetoo.com/images/firstimage.png why is the version stacks with each other? it is like i'm looking at a ghost, seriously ...

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `UNION` you can achieve this with this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM atm_mti_view
WHERE project_function='FRS01' AND
      on_big_project_id = 12          
ORDER BY IF(not_existing = 1, 1, 0) ASC,
         type_of_work ASC,
          project_version ASC;
```

Comment: this works too, incredible :) thanks, but what is the logic, i don't really understand it

Comment: Basically your `not_existing` column is either NULL or 1. NULLs are treated a bit strangely in most SQL engines since they don't equal anything else. This just eliminates the NULL by replacing the value of `not_existing` with 0 if it's not equal to 1 (since NULL is not equal to anything the NULLs are replaced by 0). Since you can order by any expression, this just creates an expression to use as the order by